# Looking for a reporting tool that will allow vector graphics in output file (PDF)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, pdf-generation, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

I have been tasked with evaluating our current system that we use for creating and outputing reports.

Currently we are using `Crystal Reports 2008`, (I know that this is and old version.), which has a custom commandline app that we wrote in C# to execute the report for a given parameter passed through the command line.

We like Crystal becuase it's easy to setup and design the report. It's also easy to print and create a PDF file from crystal using our custom commandline program.

One of the problems/complaints that we have is that Crystal does not appear to have a method that will allow us to create a PDF file with a vector images, such as our company logo. Crystal Reports always converts an image into a bitmap. When the PDF is printed, the results are less than flattering, and the PDF file size is increased.

Does anyone have any recomendadtions for a reporting product that we should consider?

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp supports importing WMF as vector image. Maybe other formats too.

See sample [here](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap0601.cs). N.B.: it seems, it's a bit outdated... you'll need to replace 'getInstance' with 'GetInstance'.

Answer (score 0):

www.hagridsolutions.com/xtraction
Offers easier use than Crystal and a rich export that can cater for exporting data into a MS Word template (that could contain vector images, headers, table of contents) and also export this into PDF or HTML format.
Design is drag-and-drop with no coding or dependence on specialized staff whatsoever.

Comment: That solution appears to be more interactive then what I'm looking for. I require a solution that can execute and create the PDF reports programatically, without any user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the reports once and have them scheduled to output to PDF, saved to the system to be viewed online or to a file system.
The dates can be rolling (as in Last Week, Last Month) and so always deliver based on what you need.
The design is drag-and-drop, the dashboards are interactive, the reports are available when you need them, and there is security to lock down access to the dashboards/reports and control of who can design dashboards/reports. The flexibility is surely there for whatever combination is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Combit's List and LAbel will fit this requirement.

[www.combit.de](http://www.combit.de)

however the support for EMFs is not perfect, it works good for small and medium complexity.